# why using struct template operator() without paramter cause a vs error: illegal use of this type as an expression

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword

```
struct teststruct
{
    template<class C>
    auto operator()()
    {
        printf("hello world");
    }
};

 teststruct T;
 T<teststruct>();
```

that casue an error :Severity Code  Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2275   'teststruct': illegal use of this type as an expression

but using

```
struct teststruct
{
    template<class C>
    auto operator()(C*)
    {
        printf("hello world");
    }
};

 teststruct T;
 T((teststruct*)(0));
```

this Compiled succeeded

i dont need one useless paramter in my function so i perform first method,
is there some way  to make first method  work? thanks

Comment: You can write it in a ugly style like `T.operator()<teststruct>();`.

Comment: @songyuanyao thanks lots,its work even ugly but ok